# Importing nu.xom.*;

Tags: java, import, xom

[image]

Hello, I am trying to import nu.xom.*;

Can anyone tell me why this import is not working. My SDK is Java 11.
Do I need to add the project library?
[image]

Comment: I will warn you that the `import main.java` strongly smells like you don't have your IDE set up properly (`src/main/java` is usually the root of your sources, and it looks like you got it configured as `src`; likely you didn't import this as a Gradle project).

Comment: Yeah, thank you for that. It's a constraint I'm working with in class. Unavoidable.

Comment: In fact, everytime I run gradle build it changes the settings in IntelliJ.. quite frustrating.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this. I needed to add the nu.xom .jar to my project library in project structure.